# How calculate dynamic sum then using filter and grops at the same time in Excel

Tags: excel, filter, sum, group

**Table**

[image: Table]

**Filter criteria**

[image: Filter criteria]

There is a table with two columns (A and B), as well as column C, which copies the names of products from column A. Column C is used for filtering (I used a different column to exclude the values "Group Total" and "Total" from the list of filter criteria.  The first 3 rows (2,3,4) in the table, are grouped into one group. Then row 5 is a count of the sum of the group ("Group Total"). Then come two more items that are not in the group. At the very end is the total sum of all products ("Total"). Column B shows the prices of these goods and the result of the calculations respectively. You can see the values of the cells in the attached pictures.

The task is as follows: the user can either filter in the group and / or out of it, as well as simultaneously minimise and maximise the group. And at any of the combinations of these actions (even if the group, for example, minimised and the value of the product name is not visible, but the filter removed, for example, one or two values, then the remaining values there should be taken into account) the sum should be counted correctly. What formula should be in cells B5 ("Group Total") and B8 ("Total").

I tried Subtotal to count only visible cells, but then the sum did not count those items that were in the collapsed group. I tried counting the group separately by simple SUM, but then when filtering in the group, the sum did not change. I tried to apply SUM or Subtotal in ("Total") via IF. But I couldn't cover all possible combinations, at some point the sum stopped being correct

Comment: Make sure the filter is applied to all columns at once and then `SUBTOTAL(109,range)` works

Comment: The subtotal updates just fine, it's just that if you "uncollapse" any values you filtered out of the group prior to collapsing show present again (as well as in the sum). You need to reclick the filter and update with `OK` to apply previous filter again. So the foula works fine, but the Filter doesn't. Maybe instead of using grouping, add a column with a group name in the column?

Comment: `SUBTOTAL(109,range)` stops counting when the group is collapsed. It thinks these values don't exist. But they do, they're just collapsed.

Comment: @P.b Sir, this is what I was referring to you, it doesnt work see even Alex is also saying that, I have tried many ways, seems like excel doesnt understands that may be it needs some recursive lambdas here

Comment: Collapse to Excel SUBTOTAL is the same as filtered and therefore is excluded from the sum. No formula is able to make the difference; you'd need vba or a different way, like an extra column mentioning the group you could filter on.

Comment: I gave the table as some small piece of my table, I have many groups and many items that are not in groups. So I started to calculate separately how many visible rows (visible) in the group. Again using SUBTOTAL (COUNT). but it doesn't work correctly for me until the end.

Comment: =IF($A32=0; SUBTOTAL(109; E3:E7;E8:E9;E11:E12;E14:E15;E17:E18;E20:E24);
 IF($B32=0; SUBTOTAL(109; E3:E7; E33; E34; E35; E36) + E32;
 IF($B33=0; SUBTOTAL(109; E3:E7; E32; E34; E35; E36) + E33;
 IF($B34=0; SUBTOTAL(109; E3:E7; E32; E33; E35; E36) + E34;
 IF($B35=0; SUBTOTAL(109; E3:E7; E32; E33; E34; E36) + E35;
 IF($B36=0; SUBTOTAL(109; E3:E7; E32; E33; E34; E35) + E36;
 SUBTOTAL(109; E3:E7; E32; E33; E34; E35; E36)))))))